# Can't Pass $_GET variable to upload.php form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, multifile-uploader

I'm using [this image uploader from codecanyon](http://codecanyon.net/item/image-multi-upload/119999?ref=quanticalabs) and am having a problem passing data from the form to upload.php (I have an ID that is passed into a GET variable from another form on another page. Here is the code:

```
        <input class="IMU" type="file" path="files/" multi="true" startOn="auto" afterUpload="link" data="'id':'selector:#id'"  maxSize="262144" allowRemove="true" />
```

That is the actual code presented by the script. I'm trying to use the data parameter found [here - towards the bottom of the page](http://tidewaterpremierproperties.com/admin/help/documentation.html) and have no clue if I'm doing it right - I doubt it as it's not working. Thanks for any help.

Comment: It has no `name` attribute, so there's nothing TO submit.

Comment: If you're uploading something via `POST`, why are you expecting variables to magically appear in `$_GET`? Are they part of the form URL?

Comment: image upload only work with POST hence if you can use $_GET to obtain values ? try using $_POST

Comment: It is part of a larger script - several files. I have upload.php (it contains all of the upload information), new_image.php?id=id-from-get-stored-here, where that input is located (the form uploads images, just doesn't store the correct id in the database table) and several javascript files that make it all work. My problem, is that I don't know how to get the ID (the $_GET variable) from new_image.php to upload.php.

Comment: in that page $var=$_GET['id']; Pass this value as a hidden variable with in form

Comment: That didn't work, I think it's the way the script is set up.